# Trouble Displaying Styles Using 'Saved' or 'Removed' Classes

Tags: css, class

I want to change the icon of this button using two classes, 'saved' and 'removed'. I've defined the styles as follows, but when using just 'saved' or 'removed', the style doesn't display correctly, and I can't find the reason. Please guide me.

**index.js**

```
<button class="icon-btn has-state saved" aria-label="Add to saved recipes">
<span class="material-symbols-outlined bookmark-add" aria-hidden="true" >bookmark_add</span>
<span class="material-symbols-outlined bookmark-add" aria-hidden="true" >bookmark</span>
</button>
```

**style.css**

```
.has-state {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-state::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  transition: var(--transition-short);
}

.has-state:where(:hover, :focus-visible):not(:active)::after {
  background-color: var(--alpha-10);
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-variation-settings: "FILL" 0, "wght" 400, "GRAD" 0, "opsz" 24;
}

.saved .bookmark-add,
.removed .bookmark {
  display: none;
}

.saved .bookmark {
  font-variation-settings: "FILL" 1;
}

.icon-btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: var(--primary-container);
  border-radius: var(--radius-circle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "the style doesn't display correctly" is meant to convey the fact that no icon appears when `saved` is on the `<button>`, it seems like you may have meant to have the class `bookmark` on the second `<span>`, instead of `bookmark-add`:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200);

.has-state {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-state::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  transition: var(--transition-short);
}

.has-state:where(:hover, :focus-visible):not(:active)::after {
  background-color: var(--alpha-10);
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-variation-settings: "FILL" 0, "wght" 400, "GRAD" 0, "opsz" 24;
}

.saved .bookmark-add,
.removed .bookmark {
  display: none;
}

.saved .bookmark {
  font-variation-settings: "FILL" 1;
}

.icon-btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: var(--primary-container);
  border-radius: var(--radius-circle);
}
```

```html
<button class="icon-btn has-state saved" aria-label="Add to saved recipes">
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined bookmark-add" aria-hidden="true">bookmark_add</span>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined bookmark" aria-hidden="true">bookmark</span>
</button>

<button class="icon-btn has-state removed" aria-label="Add to saved recipes">
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined bookmark-add" aria-hidden="true">bookmark_add</span>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined bookmark" aria-hidden="true">bookmark</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I intend that when I don't use the "removed" class, it displays both the bookmark-add and bookmark icons. But I want to define two classes, "removed" and "saved," so that based on the event performed(later), The "removed" class should display the bookmark-add icon, and the "saved" class should display the bookmark icon. However, the code I've written now displays both icons when using the "removed" class and doesn't display either when using the "saved" class. [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kk1jB1JpOkFZYzMRTj-EAKWFE8dPcHPb/view)

Comment: I understood that there was a syntactical error that has been resolved. Thank you.